# Как изменять цвет кнопким drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

у меня есть такая хмелька:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/color" />

<solid android:color="@color/color" />
<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

я ее ставлю в бакгроунд кнопки и изменяется ее размер на овальный, но цвет не меняется на тот что в хмл, цвет устанавливается тот что в colorprimary как это можно исправить

Comment: Получается в кнопке в стилях задано раскрашивание. ПОпробуйте поиграться с атрибутом с названием типа `backgroundTint`

Comment: файл стилей вообще не создан на цвет в бакгронде и бакгроундтинт не реагирует вообще

Comment: А какая именно у вас кнопка? Если MaterialButton, то там сложнее фон менять

Comment: обычная button.